# How do you know if a login problem is the result of a simulator or your code?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I have the issue that when a user logs in the homepage thereafter doesn't load properly, but when I stop the simulator and run it again (the the user is still logged in from the previous run) the page displays fine. I am wondering if this problem lies in the simulator or my code.

```
@IBAction func signInPressed(_ sender: Any) {
if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
if let userID = user?.uid {
    KeychainWrapper.standard.set((userID), forKey: "uid")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohome", sender: nil) }
if error != nil{
    print("Incorrect")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Incorrect Email or Password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else {
    if let userID = user?.uid {
    KeychainWrapper.standard.set((userID), forKey: "uid")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohome", sender: nil)
     let databaseRef = Database.database().reference() databaseRef.child("people").child(userID).child("users").setValue(self.emailField.text!)
databaseRef.child("people").child(userID).child("postID").setValue(userID)
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: @rmaddy will do.

Comment: Not even close. If you want people to take any time to help you then you should first show some of your own effort. Copy and paste your actual properly formatted method into the question so it is readable and complete.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to read the documents of signin in with email and password again.
There are lot of mistakes in the code. When you create the user it signs in automatically, you don't have to use the sign in method agin. Secondly you navigating to new screen before saving the data into database. When we have Users Defaults present why use KeychainWrapper?

First Create a model class so it will be easy for you to access the data and save data.

```
    class User {
var userId: String?
var email : String?
var password: String?
// All the other information you want

init(dictionary:[String: AnyObject]){
 userId = dictionary["userId"] as? String // "this will be your firebase node     //make no typos here you can create a constant if you want"
 email = dictionary["email"] as? String
 password = dictionary["password"] as? String
// All the other database 
}
}
```

now our model class is done it will be easy for us to save data

```
    func createUserWithEmailAndPassword(){
    if ( emailField.text != "" && passwordField.text != "" {
     let email = emailField.text
     let password = passwordField.text
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
      if error != nil {
      // create error alert how you want.
                 return
     }
    let user = user?.user
    let uid = user?.uid
    let email = user?.email
    let password = user?.password
     // saving the user data locally
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults
    userDefaults.standard.set(uid, forKey: "user_uid")
    userDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "user_email")
    // etc etc
    // after that we will be saving this user database to firebase database
   // calling firebase save user function here which we will create below
   self.registerUserToDatabase(uid: uid!, email: email!, password: password!)
       }
    }


func registerUserToDatabase(uid: String, email: String, password: String){
let userDb = Database.database().reference.child("people").child("users").child(uid)
// Make sure the key value in the below dictionary matches the User model class you var you made
let userDictionary = ["userId": uid, "email": email,"password": password] as [String: AnyObject]

userDb.updateChildValues(userDictionary) {(err ,userDb) in
if err != nil {
// alert view for error
}
let users = User(dictionary: userDictionary)
// Below we will navigate to to home screen or which ever screen you want
self.navigateToApp()
}
}
```

create a navigate to controller function

```
func navigateToApp(){
// performe seque method
}
```

// PS what is wrong with GitHub formatter

Comment: thanks. The part about putting the firebase upload after the segue is a bad mistake. Thanks for noticing. But where am I signing in after registering? This button is called Sign UP or Sign in. When the user is new is signs up and segues, but when he is not it signs him in. From all my testing it has worked. Just lately I am getting this mentioned problem when signing in again. I am relatively new and will read about differences between keychainwrapper and user defaults

Comment: how do you use that code inside the submit pressed function?

Comment: When you click sign In button you get signed into firebase, your using email and password method, if you use google signin in will sign into firebase using google crews, just use this code as it and your work will done